# Using httpservice to call a PHP function which takes parameters

Tags: apache-flex

If you look at the link below, there is some PHP code called by Flex mxml through HttpService. The PHP code has functions, but the mxml code doesn't call a specific function. How can I use httpservice to call a specific function (in my case, one which takes parameters)?

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=data_access_2.html

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be looking for RPC rather than HTTP calls.  The example you linked to uses an HTTPService.  Take a look at RemoteObject with PHP.  I suspect you are going to have to get into some layer on the server which handles AMF.  [Here's an article](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/remoteobject_sabreamf.html).

Comment: Actually this may be of use to me - http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/201/html/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Book_Parts&file=dataservices_099_09.html